# Regex to use preg_split by a dot (.)

Tags: php, regex

Hello I need split a String by "."
Have :

```
$string = "Step one (30 min aprox.).Step two.Step three $12.00. Step four ud. visit ";
```

With:

```
preg_split('/[.]/', $string)
```

I get:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Step one (30 min aprox"
  [1]=>
  string(1) ")"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Step two"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "Step three $12"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [5]=>
  string(13) " Step four ud"
  [6]=>
  string(7) " visit "
}
```

I just want this

```
[0] Step one (30 min aprox.)
[1] Step two
[2] Step three $12.00
[3] Step four ud. visit
```

The previous character (before '.') cannot be a number or special char and the next character must be an uppercase letter.

NOTE: Step * is just a example

Hope help thanks!

Comment: You state "The prev and next char cannot be a number or special char and must be a upper letter", however in your example the previous char is NOT an uppercase letter.

Comment: I've provided an answer that makes a minor adjustment to your current regular expression using a positive lookahead. This will separate your steps as expected.

Comment: @Madbreaks sorry i already fixed "next chat must be a upper letter"

Comment: You need to provide better example data if you want better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more general case, this might help.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\.\s?([A-Z])/", "*****$1", $string);
$array = explode("*****", $string);
```

I have not tested it, but I think it will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks you its works nice with my example will try with a real case!

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a better `preg_split` for your string:

```
$string = "Step one (30 min aprox.).Step two.Step three $12.00. Step four ud. visit ";
print_r( preg_split('/(?<=[^0-9])[.](?<![0-9])/', $string, 0));

Array ( 
 [0] => Step one (30 min aprox 
 [1] => ) 
 [2] => Step two
 [3] => Step three $12.00. Step four ud 
 [4] => visit )
```

This `preg_split` will split your string on all `.`s that are not surrounded by a number. Note, this means it WILL split on your first case of `(30 min aprox.).` where there is a `.` followed by a `)` and another `.`. You'll need to remove that period prior or after the `)` to get the exact sentence structure you want.

Comment: Thanks you @PenguinCoder but i'm getting

`array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Step one (30 min aprox"
  [1]=>
  string(1) ")"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Step two"
  [3]=>
  string(31) "Step three $12.00. Step four ud"
  [4]=>
  string(7) " visit "
}`

Comment: @Kas3 That is because of the way the match is splitting, that is being done on the `.` period character. Unfortunately, without a more expansive RegEx to check for a singular word, my method will always split on any period that does not have numbers surrounding it. Also, please read my last statement in the answer regarding the `)` issue. I know the RegEx doesn't give you the EXACT structure you requested but without better input constraints, the output is limited as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Try the following pattern:

```
/\.(?=(\s*)Step)/
```

Integrated into the code, like so:

```
// Split on periods that are followed possibly by 0+ spaces, and the word 'Step'
preg_split('/\.(?=(\s*)Step)/', $string)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Step one (30 min aprox.)
    [1] => Step two
    [2] => Step three $12.00
    [3] =>  Step four ud. visit 
)
```

[See it in action.](http://ideone.com/XrqDC)

Comment: Thank you ! but $string contains "Step" was just a example

Answer (score 0):

All right, second try:

```
$array = preg_split (/\.\s?Step/, $string);
$l = count ($array);
for ($i=1; $i<$l; $i++) {
    $array [$i] = 'Step' . $array [$i];
}
```

It's not the best way to make it, but it's probably the easiest way considering the fact that you're string is very inconsistent.

Comment: It will not be always a step $string was just a example but thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work on your example string

```
$string = "Step one (30 min aprox.).Step two.Step three $12.00. Step four ud. visit ";

preg_match_all("/(Step.*?)(\.(?=\s*Step)|$)/",$string,$matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $m) {
    echo $m,"\n";
}
```

The pattern looks for strings beginning with Step and which end either with the '.' character followed (looking ahead) by Step (preceded with whitespace) or the end of string character.